# Android Studio Random.org

Tags: android, android-studio, random

I'm new to APIs and Libraries and I want to know how I can implement Random.org into my app. I need a random number from 1 to 6 (I'm making a dice app) and I only need one number to be generated. I've got my API key, bu I don't know what to do next. Random.org itself isn't all that clear on what to do next exactly. Does anyone of you know the *exact* steps to make a TextView which generates a new number at the press of a button?

Comment: "Random.org itself isn't all that clear on what to do next exactly" -- apparently, create [a JSON-RPC request using their `generateIntegers` method](https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/basic) to [their endpoint URL](https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/introduction). Or, you could just use [their library](https://github.com/RandomOrg/JSON-RPC-Java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it explains how to obtain a random integer using an http request.
You will have to program that using an http client or library like okhttp or ion, so as to issue the request and get the random number in the response.

Once you get the response you can update the TextView.

There are some guidelines to use the service. I sugest you also go through that if you plan to use this service.

[HTTP Interface Description](https://www.random.org/clients/http/)

The http interface provides this example. I have changed the number of results to one as to match one dice result.

```
https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new
```

Comment: How do I use OkHttp to extract an Int value from that website?

Comment: There are many tutorials about using okhttp online. This is one http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html.  Go through it and after that if your have doubts you can open another question in SO. I hope this helps you get going.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you need **random.org**?

Secondly, you can easily generate a random number using the Java [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) Class.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int randomNumber = rnd.nextInt(6) + 1;
```

This gives a random integer between 1,2,3,4,5 or 6.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The reason is that I want the numbers to be as random as possible.

Comment: Use [`SecureRandom`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/SecureRandom.html) then.